# more name attributes in Table

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Im my SQL Server Database I have 8 tables with the same structure.
Now I want to insert in selected tables with one Java class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_Prognosen") //here I want to put all table-Names
public class AZBNachricht { ...
```

is this possible?

Comment: Well you can make a query for get all the table-Names and then save it to your entity. My strategy for this is when you finished mapping all the DB you save all the tables created in this Entity .

Comment: does it work if you simply separate it with a comma?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to accomplish what you described.

The closest to code reuse at the entity class level would be to use a `@MappedSuperclass` class where you place all the shared column names, etc and then extend that for each table implementation with differing table names.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractStructure {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue;
  private Integer id;
  private String column1;
  private String column2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Entity1 extends AbstractStructure {

}

// ... so on
```